# how to precompile assets in vendor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, asset-pipeline, precompile

in production I'm getting this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (vendor/jquery_extras.js isn't precompiled):
    26: = stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all"
    27: = javascript_include_tag "application"
    28: 
    29: = javascript_include_tag "vendor/jquery_extras"
    30: = javascript_include_tag "vendor/jquery.ba-bbq"
    31: = javascript_include_tag "vendor/moment-with-langs"
    32: = javascript_include_tag "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"
  app/views/layouts/_headers.html.haml:29:in `_app_views_layouts__headers_html_haml__4249496561736037731_30585640'
  app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:12:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_haml__4179352970330185641_30563940'
  app/controllers/items_controller.rb:82:in `new'
```

in my `config/environments/production.rb` I have:

```
# Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  # config.assets.compress = true
  config.assets.compress = false

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # list of assets that need precompilation in vendor directory
  config.assets.precompile += %w( vendor/jquery_extras.js vendor/jquery.ba-bbq.min.js vendor/moment-with-langs.min.js )
```

and in my `public/assets/` I have :

```
$ ls -1 jquery_extras* jquery.ba-bbq* moment-with-langs*
jquery.ba-bbq.min-ad74c9887b7231076917be90512e14c4.js
jquery.ba-bbq.min-ad74c9887b7231076917be90512e14c4.js.gz
jquery.ba-bbq.min.js
jquery.ba-bbq.min.js.gz
jquery_extras-7eb0ce2de6f2553ef84968dc07cec831.js
jquery_extras-7eb0ce2de6f2553ef84968dc07cec831.js.gz
jquery_extras.js
jquery_extras.js.gz
moment-with-langs.min-c30ecb28ae71b4d324d710136a628b14.js
moment-with-langs.min-c30ecb28ae71b4d324d710136a628b14.js.gz
moment-with-langs.min.js
moment-with-langs.min.js.gz
```

in my `vendor/assets` directory I have:

```
$ ls -1 vendor/assets/
fonts
images
img
javascripts
stylesheets
```

and:

```
$ ls -1 vendor/assets/javascripts/
jquery.ba-bbq.min.js
jquery_extras.js
moment-with-langs.min.js
```

here's my `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require arwa
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
//= require jquery.timepicker
//= require colorbox-rails
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require cocoon
//= require arwa
//= require_tree .
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. could you please help me?

thanks

Comment: What's in your vendor/assets?

Comment: I added the list in the question. thanks.

Comment: Files in vendor assets should be automatically included in the compilation. Why did you need to add it to the precompile list? If you remove it and run precompile, check if it gets inserted in the compiled file.

Comment: I removed the precompilation, and got the same error, I removed from the view file the `vendor/` and still got the same error.

This is what I have now in my view: 
`= javascript_include_tag "jquery_extras"`

and it's still complaining that it's not precompiled.

Comment: are you calling this in your layout? javascript_include_tag 'jquery_extras'? If so, remove it. It should already be included in your application.js file

Comment: ok, I thought it was working, but actually I didn't have the exception any more, but it seems the files aren't loaded. am I expected to find them inside the application.js? or as separate files?   I don't see them in either.

Comment: Post the contents of the top of your application.js file. The manifest part where you have //= requires. Then open your site in a browser, look at the page source and post the head section.

Comment: application.js added to the description, in the browser headers I have only application-[hash].js and the two js libraries I load in the layout from the google apis.

Comment: ok, I've added the explicit requires to my application.js for the three files. and now the javascript code seems to be in order. unfortunately for some reason chrome doesn't execute part of that code. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Ok so the files are now included. Is there an error in your Chrome console?

Comment: no errors in the console, I placed a couple of alerts in my coffeescript, and gets perfectly executed in my development box. but for some reason not in production. they DID get executed when my application.js didn't contain the inclusion of the three files. few minutes ago. but now not any more

Comment: I correct, none of the JS seems to work.

Comment: thanks anyhow, that's material for another question, the files are now loading and being precompiled, so this question is solved.  thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare with [Assets precompile Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) I found this:

in your **config/enviroments/production.rb**

```
config.assets.compress = false
```

in the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#upgrading-from-old-versions-of-rails) it is:

```ruby
# Compress JavaScripts and CSS
config.assets.compress = true

# Choose the compressors to use
# config.assets.js_compressor  = :uglifier
# config.assets.css_compressor = :yui

# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = false

# Generate digests for assets URLs.
config.assets.digest = true

# Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
# config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )
```

If you are doing local compilation, [look up here for do it](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#local-precompilation) and after that run local compilation  `$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`